# Как привязать к модели товара несколько фотографий в стандартной админке Django?

Tags: python, django

К каждому товару можно будет привязать от одного до 4 фото. Можно конечно сделать в модели вот так:

```
from django.db import models

class Product(models.Model)
    image1 = models.ImageField()
    image2 = models.ImageField()
    image3 = models.ImageField()
    image4 = models.ImageField()
```

Но, очевидно, что это колхоз и должен быть какой-то нормальный способ.

Я как-то начал думать в сторону создания отдельной модели для коллекции фоток и связывания ее с моделью товара. Но не понял как сделать так, чтобы саму эту галерею можно было создать непосредственно при добавлении товара.

Если есть модуль для этой цели, подскажите пожалуйста самый толковый и проверенный. А если можно легко обойтись без модуля - наставьте новичка на путь истинный.

Answer (score 5):

В **models.py**:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    # список остальных полей

class Gallery(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='gallery')
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='images')
```

В **admin.py**:

```
class GalleryInline(admin.TabularInline):
    fk_name = 'product'
    model = Gallery


@admin.register(Product)
class ProductAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [GalleryInline,]
```

---

Допустим есть объект `my_product = Product()`.

Обратиться к изображениям, привязанным к продукту можно двумя путями:

1. `my_product.images.all()` - где `images` - `related_name`, указанный в поле `product` модели `Gallery`.
2. `Gallery.objects.filter(product=my_product)`.

Comment: Спасибо, в админке это заработало. Вот только я не пойму как теперь получить это в шаблоне. Допустим я передал в шаблон некий object, котоырый является объектом класса Product. Пытаюсь обратиться к его фотографиям {{object.images}}, но это не работает

Comment: @КонстантинКомиссаров, используйте `{{ object.images.all() }}` для получения всех изображений(даже если загружали всего одно). В данном случае `images` - related manager: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/relations/

Comment: Спасибо, помогло, запустил цикл как 
`{% for image in object.images.all %}` и это работает)

Comment: Шикарный ответ! Спасибо за помощь!!!